# how to get new request object after ajax called

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am developing WEB PROJECT using JSP and SERVLET.

I am trying to upload file using AJAX called.
File is successfully uploaded.
but, while ajax called controller (servlet file) send request and response object to jsp file.

> JSP file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':file').change(function(){
            var fileObj = this.files[0];
                var form = $('#mOBJ');
                var fd = new FormData();    
                fd.append( 'file', fileObj);
                $.ajax({
                    url:form.attr('action'),
                    type:form.attr('method'),
                    data:fd,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    async:false,

                }).done(function(){
                    alert('ajax complete');
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here i am getting old request value.
I want new request and response object after ajax called.

```
                        var Check2Bool  = <%=context.getAttribute("comeFromUploadTemp")%>;
                        var check2 =  <%=request.getAttribute("comeFromUploadTemp")%>; 
                        alert(Check2Bool + " " + check2);

                }).fail(function() {
                    alert( "error" );
                    $('#ldiv').hide();
                });

});
```

> Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();

        /**
         * Display XML file to the user
         */
        TemplateVO template = null;
        TemplateUtil util = new TemplateUtil();

        //Prepare XML file path
        String path=(String) context.getAttribute(Constants.USER_DIR);
        String strFilePath = null;

        //Upload XML file
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            try{
                List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                for(FileItem item : multiparts){
                    if(!item.isFormField()){
                        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        request.setAttribute("FileName",name);
                        String path1 = path +  File.separator + "data-in";
                        strFilePath = FileUtil.createFileOnFileSystem(item,path1,name,"xml");
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        //set variables into Request Object
        template = util.readXML(strFilePath);

        context.setAttribute("comeFromUploadTemp", true);
        request.setAttribute("comeFromUploadTemp", true);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("mappingObject.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the request is JSP workspace, notajax.
u should pass data through response i.o. request.
like:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //... your code here
     response.getOutputStream().write(data);

}
```

then u can parse response and get data as you want.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/522069/Servlets/java/Adding-Custom-Data-Response-Headers
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp